# ocaml syntax error in REPL mode

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

This part of my code always shows me some syntx error: operator expected in the ocaml REPL. The error is on the `let` of the line "let rec projected ...". What might it be? `conditions` is defined as a `string list` and  `aTable` is  `(string list * string list* (string list) list)`

```
 let project (conditions, aTable)=(
    let trueFalseList = match aTable with 
        _,cols,_ -> dataMatcher(cols, conditions)

    let rec projected (aTable, trueFalseList) = match aTable with
        name,[],[] -> name,[],[]
      |name,cols,[] -> newLineMaker ((List.hd cols), trueFalseList)::projected(name,(List.tl cols),[])
      |name,cols,vals -> newLineMaker ((List.hd vals), trueFalseList)::projected(name,cols,(List.tl vals)) 
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines typed into an OCaml REPL in essence form an OCaml module. At the outermost level of a module you can have

```
let name = value
```

to define a global named value of the module.

In your case, you have `let project (conditions, aTable) = value`. In other words, you're defining a function `project` that takes a pair of values as its parameter.

In any places other than the outermost level of a module, there are no global names. So every `let` must be followed by `in`. This is the case in the definition of your `project` function, and is what the interpreter is complaining about. It is expecting to see `in`, or a continuation of the expression (i.e., an operator of some sort).

It's not clear what your function `project` is supposed to return. What is the type of `project` as a whole?

Comment: The project (conditions, aTable) <=> (string list, (string list * string list* (string list) list)) returns (string list * string list* (string list) list). 

The idea is kind of a relational algebra functionality i.e. to enter a table and some column names and show only the columns that are included in the conditions list.